# Problems to import ProgressDialog class

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to use `ProgressDialog` in a project, but I can not import that class into my `MainActivity.java`.

When I try to write `import android.app.ProgressDialog;` the line of code gets hidden.

This problem occurs in all projects, even a new and empty project.

[MainActivity.java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uI2u0RmqhRHK6kbFXh7hBMuSxTlhqRz4)

[app.gradle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1od8IYP5kRS7InLadunKdgSy7r-lKmF57/view)

[the error I got](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZU6jFPMg1MPbXUqFZOsxkYq3qsebHTQ2/view)

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Problem is, its class does not add to the program. You should be asking for `why`

Comment: Please do not give a negative rating, I am a beginner.
and I can not speak English well.

Comment: But you should at least learn [ask] a question properly, on this site.

Comment: @Fantômas I edited my question

Comment: The IDE you are using is **totally irrelevant**. What is relevant for a good post is; your current code and the error you get, if any. Eventually, with some image describing the desired goal and/or issue visually.

Comment: @Fantômas Now can you help me about my problem?

Comment: No. Still too little information, really. Try to be more specific. We don't see what you see. Nor we can imagine that.

Comment: My rating is low on this site. Because of this, I can not send the photo :(

Comment: Please paste your complete activity code by editing the question, that will help to understand your problem, also paste the gradle file for convenience.

Comment: You can post the *code*. And the link to the photo (just in case). Someone (...) will convert it for you.

Comment: I even have a new project and I do not write any code inside it, it's still a problem, It seems that the ProgressDialog class in android studio has been cleared.

Comment: a screenshot of project: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uI2u0RmqhRHK6kbFXh7hBMuSxTlhqRz4)

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your `app.gradle` file?

Comment: @sourav.bh Do you mean this? [app.gradle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1od8IYP5kRS7InLadunKdgSy7r-lKmF57)

Comment: @Fantômas When I compile the program, this error occurs : [error: cannot find symbol class ProgressDialog](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZU6jFPMg1MPbXUqFZOsxkYq3qsebHTQ2)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the screenshots. I have edited your post to include that two screenshots and made an answer to your problem.

Comment: @sourav.bh Thanks for Editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was solved.**

I deleted the `android studio` and also

(important -->)

deleted the `gradle` folder and the `android studio 3.2` folder and reinstalled `android studio`.

Finally my problem was resolved.

[Screenshot for gradle & androidstudio folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuVtR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong in your project settings from the screenshots you attached. I would suggest you to try `Invalidate Cache / Restart` from the **File** menu.

[image]

Comment: @Daniel what happens when you write `import android.app.ProgressDialog;` this manually? In your post, you mentioned that line gets hidden but that doesn't clear the situation.

Comment: my problem was solved. Thank you for giving me your time.

Comment: nice to hear that you solved it yourself. mark your answer as accepted so that others find it useful.